# Как рассчитать вес компонентов ПК в java

Tags: java, enum

Столкнулся с проблемой- не понимаю как посчитать вес компонентов ПК. Информацию о компонентах выводит, а вод конструктор на расчет веса не понимаю как написать. Код ниже:

```
public class Computer {
    private final String vendor;
    private final String name;
    private Processor processor;
    private Ram ram;
    private Hdd hdd;
    private Screen screen;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    private double totalWeight;

    public Computer(String vendor, String name, Processor processor, Ram ram,
                    Hdd hdd, Screen screen, Keyboard keyboard, double totalWeight) {
        this.vendor = vendor;
        this.name = name;
        this.processor = new Processor(processor.getProcessorFrequency(), processor.getNumberOfCores(),
                processor.getProcessorManufacturer(), processor.getProcessorType(),
                processor.getProcessorWeight());
        this.ram = new Ram(ram.getRamAmount(), ram.getRamType(), ram.getRamWeight());
        this.hdd = new Hdd(hdd.getMemoryAmount(), hdd.getHddType(), hdd.getHddWeight());
        this.screen = new Screen(screen.getScreenDiagonal(), screen.getScreenType(),
                screen.getScreenWeight());
        this.keyboard = new Keyboard(keyboard.hasBacklight(), keyboard.getKeyboardType(),
                keyboard.getKeyboardWeight());
        this.totalWeight = totalWeight;
    }

    public Computer setVendor(String vendor) {
        return new Computer(vendor, name, processor, ram,
                 hdd,  screen, keyboard, totalWeight);
    }

    public String getVendor(){return vendor;}

    public Computer setName(String name) {
        return new Computer(vendor, name, processor, ram,
                 hdd,  screen, keyboard, totalWeight);
    }

    public String getName(){return name;}

    public void calculateTotalWeight() {
        totalWeight = processor.getProcessorWeight() + ram.getRamWeight() +
        hdd.getHddWeight() + screen.getScreenWeight() + keyboard.getKeyboardWeight();
    }

    public double getTotalWeight(){
        return totalWeight;
    }

    public String toString(){return "Производитель ПК: " + vendor + "\n" + "Имя ПК: " + name +
            "\n" + processor + "\n" + ram + "\n" + hdd + "\n" + screen + "\n" + keyboard +
            "Общий вес " + totalWeight + "грамм";}
}
```

И класс Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Computer computer = new Computer("China", "ПК Пети",
                new Processor(1.9,4, "Intel",
                        ProcessorType.BUFFERPROCESSOR, 10),
                new Ram(4, RamType.SDRAM, 4),
                new Hdd(500, HddType.HDD, 500),
                new Screen(17, ScreenType.IPS, 10),
                new Keyboard(true, KeyboardType.CONDUCTIVE, 1200),
                1);
        System.out.println(computer);
    }
}
```

В консоль выводит:

```
Производитель ПК: China
Имя ПК: ПК Пети
Частота процессора: 1.9 Ггц
Количество ядер: 4
Производитель: Intel
Вес процессора 10.0 грамм
Тип процессора: BUFFERPROCESSOR
Объём оперативной памяти: 4 ГБ
Тип оперативной памяти: SDRAM
Вес планки оперативной памяти 4.0 грамм
Объём памяти: 500 ГБ
Тип жесткого диска: HDD
Вес жесткого диска 500.0 грамм
Диагональ экрана: 17 дюймов
Тип экрана: IPS
Вес монитора 10.0 кг.
Наличие подсветки: true
Тип клавиатуры: CONDUCTIVE
Вес клавиатуры 1200.0 граммОбщий вес 1.0грамм
Общий вес1.0
```

А нужно, чтобы вес всех компонентов суммировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто замените в конструкторе строчку:

```
this.totalWeight = totalWeight;
```

на вот эту:

```
this.totalWeight = calculateTotalWeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public double calculateTotalWeight() {
    return processor.getProcessorWeight() + ram.getRamWeight() +
    hdd.getHddWeight() + screen.getScreenWeight() + keyboard.getKeyboardWeight();
}
```

и в конструкторе:

```
public Computer(String vendor, String name, Processor processor, Ram ram,
                Hdd hdd, Screen screen, Keyboard keyboard, double totalWeight) {
    ...
    this.totalWeight = calculateTotalWeight();
}
```